# $rootScope.$digest is clearing params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pushstate, angularjs-digest

I have problem with `window.history.pushState` method. I'm on page `https://localhost:1234/jobs`. I want to add one parameter and hash to my url without reloading a page. I have a simple button to edit job:

```
<i class="fas fa-edit fa-fw"
   data-tooltip="tooltip"
   title="Edit this job"
   ng-click="goJobModal(job.id);$event.stopPropagation()"></i>
```

After pressing this, `goJobModal` should be executed with `job.id`

```
$scope.goJobModal = function(jobId) {
  if (jobId) {
    window.history.pushState(null, "Updating job", "/jobs/?jobId=" + jobId + "#update");
    console.log(window.location.href);
  } else {
    window.history.pushState(null, "Creating job", "/jobs#create");
  }
};
```

I placed a breakpoint in line with `console.log` to look what happens after pushState and I saw something iteresting for me. After `$rootScope.$digest` my url was cleared to `https://localhost:1234/jobs`. What should I do to successfully change my url?

Comment: What are you trying to achive? You know there is a routing system in AngularJS?

Comment: I need to change my url without reloading page. I read that, pushState method should change my url and dont reload page. This works for jobs#create, but when I'm trying to achieve the same effect for Updating job it doesn't work.